# How to install Evalvid on ubuntu?steps?

Tags: software-installation

I'm setting Evalvid in ns2 on Ubuntu. What do steps install it?

Who can help me! I try it flowing "Smallko" but not success .Who take for me How to set up it?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Open the terminal and install the following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ python              
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ python python-dev
sudo apt-get install mercurial
sudo apt-get install bzr
sudo apt-get install gdb valgrind
sudo apt-get install gsl-bin libgsl0-dev libgsl0ldbl
sudo apt-get install flex bison libfl-dev
sudo apt-get install g++-3.4 gcc-3.4
sudo apt-get install tcpdump
sudo apt-get install sqlite sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install vtun lxc
sudo apt-get install uncrustify
sudo apt-get install doxygen graphviz imagemagick 
sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-extra
sudo apt-get install python-sphinx dia
sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-signals-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
sudo apt-get install openmpi*
```

Step-2: Download the all-in-one tar.gz file from http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/

Step-3: untar it using "tar zxvf ns-allinone-xxx.tar.gz"
Once all files are extracted enter into the directory through the terminal and run "./install". Once installed the terminal will look something like this and will ask you to add some directoties to your PATH environment.

Step-4: PATH is an enviroment variable. Basically, it tells your machine were to search for programs.
Open a new terminal and edit the following file from your home directory using:

```
"gedit ~/.profile"
```

find the following line: PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
and add a colon and paste the given directory.... something like this - `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:~/Desktop/Cop/ns-allinone-2.35/bin".`

Step-5:  Add two more environment variables as shown in the terminal for LD_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY as follows:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/Desktop/Cop/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:~/Desktop/Cop/ns-allinone-2.35/lib`"

```
export TCL_LIBRARY_PATH="~/Desktop/Cop/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library"
```

Step-6: Now NS2 has been installed and configured.... to validate it do the following:

```
cd ns-2.35
./validate
```

One last step....to start using the network simulator install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ns2 nam xgraph
```

[check this blog](http://totalgeekout.blogspot.com/)

Comment: i have install NS2.and now How to do i to add Evalvid?thanhks

Comment: This is  proplem.i can't resolve it.configure: error: Installation of tcl seems incomplete or can't be found automatically.
Please correct the problem by telling configure where tcl is
using the argument --with-tcl=/path/to/package
(perhaps after installing it),
or the package is not required, disable it with --with-tcl=no.